# Variables based on targets in Makefile

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, command-line, makefile

when creating a Makefile, im trying to figure out how(if) i can change a variable based on the target.

So something likes this:

```
VER = $(if target=release then 1.0.0 elseif target=nightly then 20110411)

nightly:
    @@echo ${VER} >> version.txt

release:
    @@echo ${VER} >> version.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `make` is GNU make,
[Target-Specific Variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)
is allowed.
For example, in your question's case, the following definitions will meet the
purpose:

```
nightly: VER = 20110411
release: VER = 1.0.0

nightly:
    @echo ${VER}

release:
    @echo ${VER}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I consistently get this error with your approach `Makefile:6: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.`  With the number being the line number of the target

Comment: Is your `make` GNU-make? If so, what is the version? The above code worked
when I tested on GNU-make 3.80 and 3.81.
If your `make` isn't GNU-make, unfortunately the answer may not apply.

Comment: @Ise Wisteria GNU Make 3.81
This program built for i386-apple-darwin10.0

Comment: @Ise Wisteria Using the original code I have, could you make the changes you suggested so I can see if I was implementing them correctly?

Comment: If your `makefile` is small enough, I may be able to find out the cause.
However, if the file isn't small, I'm not confident I can...
My test code is exactly above. So, could you test the code and see the
results?
Probably `make nightly` will echo `20110411`, and `make release` will
echo `1.0.0`.